# Pygame creating multiple objects instead of moving only one

Tags: python, class, methods, pygame

I'm trying to move a single image around the screen in Pygame using methods controlled by the keyboard, but it appears to be creating duplicates in those positions instead of moving the original image. Why is this happening, given that the image is created before entering the main loop?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()



DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

posx = 10
posy = 10

class Hero():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = posx
        self.y = posy

    def appearance(self):
        return pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\right.png')

    def move_right(self):
        self.x += 25
        return self.x

    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= 25
        return self.x

    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 25
        return self.y

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 25
        return self.y

new_hero = Hero() #create a Hero
item = new_hero.appearance() #create one reference 



while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

             if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                posx = new_hero.move_left()

             elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                posx = new_hero.move_right()

             elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                posy = new_hero.move_up()

             elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                posy = new_hero.move_down()

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(item, (posx, posy)) 



    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: you have to clear screen before you draw new elements. ie. fill with black color `DISPLAYSURF.fill( (0,0,0) )` or `blit` some background which will remove everthing on `DISPLAYSURF`

Comment: [simple template](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py) to organize code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put in code to delete all the past images.

This is the basic layout of a pygame project. You should ALWAYS (if you do not have a background image) fill the screen with white after updating.

```
white = 255, 255, 255
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()
    pygame.display.update()
```